# Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleProcessor' less than -source '1.8'

Tags: java, android, java-8

what is this errpr ?
Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleProcessor' less than -source '1.8'

we added

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }
```

in gradle and no use;

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
```

Comment: Another version of the error is `Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor' less than -source '1.8'` which I got after upgrading Android Studio, gradle, dependencies, etc.